# Php / AngularJs / Ionic Request header field Authorization is not allowed

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, ionic-framework, cors

First of all I want to say that I tried All stackoverflow solutions and no one works for me :(

In my server config I have got this

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
// respond to preflights
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
// return only the headers and not the content
// only allow CORS if we're doing a GET - i.e. no saving for now.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
}
exit;
}
```

And in my application I have been config  the $httpProvider.

```
.config(['$httpProvider',
    function($httpProvider) {
        function tokenInjector($localStorage) {
             return {
                 request: function(config) {
                     if ($localStorage.token) {
                         config.headers.authorization = 'Basic ' + $localStorage.token;
                     } else {
                         delete config.headers.authorization;
                     }

                     return config;
                 }
             };
        }
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(tokenInjector);

    }
])

.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = false;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
});
```

The service call ( Headers with token have been set in the $httpProvider.interceptors )

```
$http.get('http://myurl')
```

The question is..... I don't know why but in my mobile phone ( Android or iOS ) works fine but... in my web browser not. I tried in chrome, mozilla and safari.
If I install the Chrome plugin CORS works fine if not always returns that error

> Failed to load resource: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://myurl. Request
>   header field Authorization is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

How can I fix that in my browser without CORS plugin?

Thanks to all who want to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not server issue please check this link:

http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Then this link:

[api calling error in ionic-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048101/api-calling-error-in-ionic-framework/38048290#38048290)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :) Works fine that solution, you save my day